# RCP icons with decorator have black background on macOS

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

When in my RCP application a decorator is added to an icon in a TreeViewer, the background of the icon is black on macOS.

[image]

The decorator shown is simple:

```
public class GroupDecorator extends LabelProvider implements ILightweightLabelDecorator {

  public static final String IMAGE_PATH = "overlays/folder_decorator.png";

  @Override
  public void decorate(Object o, IDecoration decoration) {
    if(o instanceof Group<?> 
       && !(o instanceof IISO27Scope)
       && !(o instanceof Asset)
       && !(o instanceof ImportBpGroup)) {
        decoration.addOverlay(ImageCache.getInstance().getImageDescriptor(IMAGE_PATH));
    }
  }
}
```

Full source code is on GitHub: [GroupDecorator.java](https://github.com/SerNet/verinice/blob/768fb52cf8f052f1329090f6ed20286e20defb50/sernet.gs.ui.rcp.main/src/sernet/verinice/iso27k/rcp/GroupDecorator.java)

You can find the decorator image file here: [overlays/folder_decorator.png](https://github.com/SerNet/verinice/blob/768fb52cf8f052f1329090f6ed20286e20defb50/sernet.gs.ui.rcp.main/icons/overlays/folder_decorator.png)

Eclipse RCP version is 2019-06 / 4.12. MacOS version is Catalina 10.15.2. The shown problem does **not** occur on Linux and on Windows. It also does **not** occur with Eclipse RCP 4.7 on macOS Catalina.

How can I make the background white?

Comment: Expecting us to look at a complete github project is not how Stack Overflow works, show us a [mre]. There are lots of things that might be an issue - for example IDecoration.addOverlay adds an overlay on to an existing image - it might be that base image that is wrong.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the same icons are displayed correctly without decorator.

Comment: I don't expect you to read the complete source code on GitHub. However, there might be a bug in SWT, or a simple fix in the source code I posted will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the SWT bug - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=310387 and has been fixed in Eclipse 2020-03.

Comment: Can the problem be solved with a work around without updating the target platform?